# File is not part of the project or Build Action not set to "Resource"

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I get the error

> The file /DocomGUI;component/Resources/logo.jpg is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' property is not set to 'Resource'.

But the `logo.jpg` file is definitely part of the project and the Build Actions is also set to "Resource".

[image: Project structure]
[image: File properties]

It resides within the `/Resources/` folder in the root of the project and is also in the `Resources.resx` file with the same name.

[image: Resources file]

I tried rebuilding the solution, cleaning it and still, the error pops up. What else could go wrong so that the file can't be found?

The code:

```
<Window x:Class="DocomGUI.AboutWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AboutWindow" Height="180" Width="220" Background="LightGray" MinWidth="220" MinHeight="115" MaxWidth="220" MaxHeight="115">
    <Grid>
        <Label Margin="0,66,24,48">DocomGUI</Label>
        <Label Height="30" Margin="12,0,12,12" Name="VersionLabel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Label>
        <Image Margin="12,12,12,0" Stretch="Fill" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/DocomGUI;component/Resources/logo.jpg" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Probably a blanking to remove company name. ;)

Comment: Exactly right ;-) Sorry about that - And before you come into temptation: no, the filename is correct everywhere ^^

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: Also considering casing etc.? Can you get it to work for say, the folder icon?

Comment: Yes. All other images can be used without problems in the same window.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: (You needd to use `@` notation if there are more than two people.) Then you probably do reference it incorrectly, if all the settings are the same and all the other images work this seems to be the only thing that is left which could cause such an error.

Comment: @H.B. I added the complete code of the window that causes the error.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: And you did rename the logo file accordingly?

Comment: I solved this problem once by simply restarting visual studio, it's worth a try if everything seems correct otherwise.

Comment: @KDiTraglia I just restarted it, and, oh wonder: It works now without changing anything. I guess what they say about windows (Windows? Reboot! Linux? Be root!) is also true for applications... You may add that as an answer... although it's pretty dull :)

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: That was anticlimactic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has happened to me before, and it actually fixed itself simply by restarting visual studio.  I'm not really sure why.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you declare it in the window.resources like this:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="logo" UriSource="/Resources/logo.jpg" />
```

and use it like this?

```
<Image Margin="12,12,12,0" Stretch="Fill" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{StaticResource logo}" />
```

I'm suggesting this because I once had a similar problem and this workaround worked out for me.